# Quartz throwing SchedulerException: DB URL not specified for DataSource

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

**Environment :**

Project is having org.quartz-scheduler.quartz:2.3.2 library which comes from org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz dependency.

**Problem :**

QuartzConfig.class: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: **DB URL not specified for DataSource: myDS**

**Goal :**

Goal is to have two seperate scheduler having **separate configurations and seperate HikariCP DB connection pool**.

---

---

**I have this following quartz2.properties :**

```
# Configure the Quartz Scheduler
# Configure the HikariCP DataSource
org.quartz.datasource.myDS.URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5442/reports
org.quartz.datasource.myDS.jdbcUrl=${spring.datasource.url}
org.quartz.datasource.myDS.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
org.quartz.datasource.myDS.username=app
org.quartz.datasource.myDS.password=app
org.quartz.datasource.myDS.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
org.quartz.datasource.myDS.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider = hikaricp
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 10

spring.datasource.myDS.URL=${spring.datasource.url}

#org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


# Configure the ThreadPool for Quartz
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 9

# Configure the JobStore
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=nightly-quartz-scheduler
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime=5000
org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.class=org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=quartz.QRTZ_NIGHTLY_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
```

Spring boot application startup fails with the exception :
**SchedulerException: DB URL not specified for DataSource**

```
o.s.b.f.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean' defined in class path resource [./config/QuartzConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: DB URL not specified for DataSource: myDS\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)\n\tat o.s.b.f.c.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)\n\tat o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDe..."
```

Also I have the following configuration in **application.properties** :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5442/reports
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=${spring.datasource.url}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=reporting_app
spring.datasource.password=reporting_app
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

---

---

Followed the steps mentioned here also : http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigDataSources.html